# jQuery each() function to append element to each form based on its id

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I'm trying to loop through the list of forms displayed on the page and append element to each of them depending on their id.

I thought of doing something like this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var number_of_forms = $('.common_form_class').length;

if (number_of_forms > 1) {
    $('.common_form_class').each(function() {
        var identity = $(this).attr('id');
        $.getJSON("/token.php?key=" + identity, function(data){
            $(this).append('<input type="hidden" class="token" name="token" value="'+data.token+'" />');
        });
    });
} else {
    var identity = $('.common_form_class').attr('id');
    $.getJSON("/token.php?key=" + identity, function(data){
        $('.common_form_class').append('<input type="hidden" class="token" name="token" value="'+data.token+'" />');
    });
}
```

I understand that I can't refer to the form within the each() loop by using $(this), but does anyone know how could I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you not think that you can use `$(this)` in the `.each`?  You may want to capture it before your callback though, `var $form = $(this);   /* other code*/ funciton(data) { $form.append(...); }` should work.

Comment: Well - I don't think I can refer to the element which I currently loop through by using $(this). I know I can pass index or key => value pair as parameters of the first argument (function), but don't think I can use $(this) to refer to the element itself?

Comment: Yes, you can refer to each form using $(this). Can you be more specific on what doesn't work? Any error message?

Comment: By the way, it seems that if condition makes no sense. Both blocks are doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes - sorry I've corrected the code - if there was just one form found on the page I refer to it as : var identity = $('.common_form_class').attr('id');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your code using better style, please test:

```
$('.common_form_class').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.getJSON("/token.php", {key: $this.attr('id')}, function(data){
        $this.append($("<input/>", {type: "hidden", "class": "token", name: "token"}).val(data.token));
    });
});
```

Comment: Using the variable name `$this` might be confusing. It looks like a failed `$(this)`. +1 for using the data object in the `getJSON` call though.

Comment: @Guffa: I see where you are coming from -- however I do prefer to start the variable name with $ if it refers to a jQuery object.

Comment: Great - I've changed var $this for var frm - but all together great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That only works if you have more than one form. If there is only one form you are trying to use `$(this)` without an `each` loop, so `this` will be the `window` object.

Also, using `$(this)` inside the callback doesn't work, because the callback is executed later, outside the scope of the loop. Store the reference to the form in a local variable, so that it's inlcuded in the closure for the callback function.

You can just loop even if there is only one form:

```
$('.common_form_class').each(function() {
  var frm = $(this);
  $.getJSON("/token.php?key=" + frm.attr('id'), function(data){
    frm.append('<input type="hidden" class="token" name="token" value="'+data.token+'" />');
  });
});
```

Or making a bit better use of jQuery:

```
$('.common_form_class').each(function(i, frm) {
  $.getJSON("/token.php", { key: frm.attr('id') }, function(data){
    frm.append($('<input/>', { type: 'hidden', 'class': 'token', name: 'token' }).val(data.token));
  });
});
```

Note: By using the `val` method to set the value instead of concatenating it into the HTML code, you don't have to worry about characters that could break the HTML code.